# What episode of "Star Trek" shows a planet where time runs eerily fast?

Tags: star-trek, episode-identification

I can remember watching a *Star Trek* episode where the crew entered a region of space where time runs much faster than on board of the Enterprise.

At a given moment there is a planet visible, seen from outer space, and one can see that they had entered the atomic era: bright short flashes of light were seen on the surface, indicating the testing of the first atomic bombs (though it could also be that they started a nuclear conflict).

It was the *Star Trek* series with that female captain.

Comment: TOS Wink of an Eye also has an ultra time speed planet - though you want the voyager episode already answered.

Comment: @lucasbachman Why is that episode so much less ranked (I saw this in the links)?

Comment: Probably because it is a "bottle" episode meaning it mostly takes place on the ship.  And it mostly just Kirk being annoyed by his situation and doesn't make a lot of sense compared to a better episode where Kirk can give some speech about the need to act civilized or the nobility of not being controlled by a computer.

Comment: @Deschele I enjoyed TOS *Wink of an Eye* when I was a young kid, but as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wink_of_an_Eye) explains, it's full of plot holes and incoherent science.

Comment: Re, "Wink of an Eye," Plot holes aside, That episode wasn't explained as anything messing with the flow of time. It supposedly was some handwavium in the water that made Kirk and the natives of the planet live at super-speed.

Comment: @PM2Ring Hi there! I didnt see that one. I can remember the Blink very well though. But I couldnt remember the name of that show. It apparantly made an impression on me as I can remember those exploding boms vividly. I even dreamt about it. Always nice to read your comments!;)

Comment: There's also that DS9 episode, [Children of Time](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Children_of_Time_(episode)), in which time doesn't move faster, but there's a similar experience in that the DS9 people meet Odo  200 years older, and their own descendents after 200 years, due to a time-travel effect.

Comment: @PM2Ring you just described the entirety of TOS.

Comment: @SolomonSlow (fitting name...:))Is there a difference? Between time going faster or living faster?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder, I don't want to open a discussion of what "time" means, and whether it makes sense to talk about it "moving" at any speed. But, the weird things that happened in "Wink of an Eye" did not happen to anybody who visited a particular place. They happened to characters who _drank the water_ from a particular source.

Comment: @SolomonSlow The drink made their atoms move faster?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That should be "[Blink of an Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_of_an_Eye_(Star_Trek:_Voyager))", Season 6 episode 12 of Star Trek: Voyager.

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_of_an_Eye_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)):

> The episode follows the crew's interaction with a world where time passes rapidly, allowing them to witness most of its inhabitants' history. For the inhabitants, Voyager is fixed in the night sky, inspiring them as the eons pass.

(found with google search: "star trek voyager episode planet faster time")

Comment: That's the one! Thanks. I wanna see it afain. I guess I could have looked it up too...Maybe Im too lazy.:)I accept after 7 minutes.

Comment: Essentially the same plot was used in an episode of The Orville;  "Mad Idolatry", season 1, episode 12.  If you'd like to do a comparison!

Comment: It's also a rather blatant rip-off of the novel Dragon's Egg. I'm told if you like that episode you'll probably love the novel.

Comment: I recently read Dragon's Egg - very highly recommended.

Comment: It's a pretty obvious and basic sci-fi idea. I don't think you can call one a rip-off of another.

Comment: For just about any SF-nal idea, some writer somewhere probably came with up already.  It's the execution of the idea that's important...

Comment: @poncho Very true!

Comment: This was the most interesting VOY episode IMO. Especially where they make it up to Voyager in special suits to slow down their time rate to be able to survive in Voyager’s time rate. It was a good story!!

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Is seven minutes your normal accepting window, or is time running quicker on this post? :P

Comment: @45266 I guess my mind forgot to keep track of time altoghter. The 7 minutes were lost in time... ;D (I accepted a few hours later) To be even more clear, i got the message I could accept after 8 minutes so, minus 1 I cant stop laughing!

Comment: @MissouriSpartan It was good indeed! It made an impression on me. A lasting one. Its the only episode I can recall well. But I didnt know the title. I could have googled it I guess. But Im glad I didnt!